# Internet Explorer and Visual Studio 2008 error with document.createElementNS

Tags: internet-explorer, visual-studio-2008

I have a project in Visual Studio 2008 with some html pages and JavaScript. My IE suddenly started to behave strangely when I run the project to debug. Even on a simple HTML page, if I put for example a JS function like this:

```
function test() {
    var svgNS = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"; 
    var mySvg = document.createElementNS(svgNS, "svg");
    alert("Done!"); 
}
```

I suddenly get this error when I run the page in IE: "Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'createElementNS'". I get the same error if I try to use the canvas on the cal to  .getContext2d. If I debug and examine the document object I can see for example the method createElementNS, but calling it gives the above error.

When I make Chrome my default browser and run the page from Visual Studio, I do NOTget any error. Also, when I put the page on a web server, I can view it in IE without an error! I am completely baffled. It seems as if my IE and Visual Studio combination is somehow broken.

I am hoping someone has run into something like this before and will appreciate any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Which version of IE are you using? Debugging a page in IE8 with VS2008 is implemented very hacky. `createElementNS` is supported since IE9. I think IE8 supports SVG only as a pure SVG document. You can mix HTML with SVG since IE9.

Comment: Thanks vasek7. I am using IE9. To confirm, everything was working fine until this came up. While testing, I switch all the time from IE to Chrome to Safari (making one or the other the default browser). My suspicion is somehow IE is now acting as IE8. But that does not explain why I can view my page correctly from IE when it is on a web server as opposed to localhost.

Comment: Oh, I see. You probably need to force an IE9 document mode. Try to add this meta tag `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9">`.

Comment: That solved the problem, thanks so much!! If you or anyone has any idea why I did not need this before but now does, please let me know.

Comment: That's because IE on the intranet has a different render mode decision algorithm than on the internet. Here you can find how it works: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ie/archive/2010/03/02/how-ie8-determines-document-mode.aspx

Comment: Glad I asked, I was completely ignorant of this issue. Thanks again for taking the time to help me. Have a nice day!

Comment: @Fritz45 - Turn off Compatibility View for intranet sites under ["Tools" > "Compatibility View Settings" > Uncheck "Display intranet sites in Compatibility View"](http://i.stack.imgur.com/9HWvN.png).  Then you shouldn't need the X-UA-Compatible tag.

Comment: Thanks gilly3, I was also not aware of that setting. Have done so on my machine but will leave the X-UA tag in case we do testing on other machines. Thanks for taking the time to help.